# How to extract the authors and links from articles using rentrez?

Tags: r, list, pubmed

I am using the RENTREZ package, to retrieve titles from PubMed authors. I first make the summary:

`papers_summary <- (entrez_summary(db = "pubmed", web_history =      r_search$web_history))`

I then try to retrieve the authors with the function below, but I haven't managed.
`paper_authors <- extract_from_esummary(papers_summary, elements = "authors", simplify = F)`

With this code I get a list of dataframes, but I would like to get only the list of authors from each article.

This is an example of output I get, but the list of these elements goes on for hundreds of times:

```
R: paper_authors
$`24533571`
$`24533571`$`authors`
       name authtype clusterid
1     Trittun F   Author          
2 Solboreisen B   Author          
3      Gianni C   Author
```

I also would like to get the link of every article but I don't know how.

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't we need the result of `dput(r_search$web_history)` to attempt a coding answer?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just added an example of the output